# React-Native - Return to Sign in screen if unauthenticated user

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to react/native and this is my first app.

I want to protect some screens which only an authenticated user can access. I read some articles and Questions. But I am still not able to get them either because they are class based or some for react.

I made a few attempts at it. One of them that seemed to work is like this.

OrderList.js

```
import IsUserLoggedIn from '../utilities/authHelpers';
import UserSignin from './UserSignin';

const OrderList = ({ route, navigation }) => {
...
...

 if(!IsUserLoggedIn){
        return <UserSignin/>
    }

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            {renderOrders()}
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}
export default OrderList;
```

This shows Signin screen. But it also runs all other logic like REST API calls, that is made in `useEffect` before `IsLoggedIn` check returns the Singin screen. I tried putting the check before those calls but then react-native complaints about returning too early. I also tried, before the `useEffect` etc, the navigation to signin route. That again didn't work. React-native throws warning that it cannot redirect from one component to another while it is still rendering. I don't recall exact message but it along those lines.

Another issue with this is that I will need to add this check in each of the protected screens. I want something that sits before all screens like in Navigators.

navigators/drawer.js

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const DrawerNav = () => {
  return (
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home"  
      >
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={StackNav} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Sign In" component={UserSignin} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="My Orders" component={OrderList} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Profile" component={UserProfile} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Change Password" component={ChangePassword} />

        <Drawer.Screen name="Forgot Password" component={ForgotPassword}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Sign Up" component={UserSignup}/>
      </Drawer.Navigator>
  )
}

export default DrawerNav;
```

I have read about HOC(High Order Components) that some have suggested in this case. But I don't understand how that is implemented in this case.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 2**

I finally got it working with few changes.

The main thing is that you need to make sure component are re-rendered. This happens only when props or state is updated. But in my case, I save authentication tokens in  local storage and that doesn't  affect state of the app, thus no re-rendering. Local state in drawer.js had no effect except the first time app started. If user signed in they need to refresh the app to make drawer get new state.

So I put another state in redux store. It is global store and I update it whenever a user is successfully logged in.

**drawer.js**

```
import {useSelector} from "react-redux";
import { OrderList, RequireAuthentication } from "../screens"

const DrawerNav = () => {
    const isLoggedIn = useSelector(state => state.userSigninState?.user_is_signed_in)

    return (
      <Drawer.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home" 
        >
        <Drawer.Screen name="My Orders" component={RequireAuthentication(OrderList, isLoggedIn)} />

     
  )
}

export default DrawerNav;
```

**RequireAuthentication.js**

```
import UserSignin from './UserSignin';

const RequireAuthentication = (protectedScreen, isLoggedIn) => {
    
    // This is a HOC()Higher Order Component).
    // It will be used to make sure protected screens are not accessible to anyone accept authenticated user.


    return (
        isLoggedIn!=true?UserSignin:protectedScreen

        )
}

export default RequireAuthentication;
```

**reducers.js**

```
const initialUserSignin = {
    user_is_signed_in:false

}

export function userSigninReducer(state=initialUserSignin, action){
    if(action.type == USER_SIGNIN_STATUS_UPDATED){
        return {
                ...state,
                user_is_signed_in: action.payload.is_signed_in,
           
            };
    } else {
        return state
    }
}
```

**actions.js**

```
export function userSigninStatusUpdated(user_signed_in){
    return {
        type:USER_SIGNIN_STATUS_UPDATED,
        payload:{
            is_signed_in:user_signed_in
        }
    }
}
```

Signin.js

```
import store from "../redux/store";
import {userSigninStatusUpdated} from '../redux/actions';

// This is when user signs in. We save their tokens and also update their signin state to true

await AsyncStorage.setItem('access_token', response.data.access);
await AsyncStorage.setItem('refresh_token', response.data.refresh);
store.dispatch(userSigninStatusUpdated(true));
```

In signout logic you will set the state to false like this:
store.dispatch(userSigninStatusUpdated(false));

I haven't implemented signout logic yet but you would also want to remove the tokens on signout.

Hope this helps someone.

**UPDATE 1**
This doesn't work. The issue is the async nature of `IsUserLoggedIn()`. I will try to fix that and post an update.

**Original Answer**

Answering my own question.

Screens or components are just functions. An HOC(High Order Component) is also a function but it can take another function(screen or component) as parameter or return another function.

So we create an HOC(a function) and pass to it our protected screen(a function) as parameter.
Inside our HOC we check if the user is logged in. If they are then we return the screen(that we passed as parameter to HOC) else we return Signin screen(again a function).

That is the main logic. I want this check to happen in navigators. So instead of having our protected screen directly mention in the params for the navigator we mention our HOC with our screen passed to that as param.

Below is my code .

RequireAuthentication.js // This is inside my screens directory.

```
import React from "react";
import IsUserLoggedIn from '../utilities/authHelpers'
import UserSignin from './UserSignin';

const RequireAuthentication = (protectedScreen) => {
    // This is an HOC(Higher Order Component).
    // It will be used to make sure protected screens are not accessible to anyone accept authenticated user.
    
        return (
           !IsUserLoggedIn()? UserSignin: protectedScreen
        )
}

export default RequireAuthentication;
```

The navigator, drawer.js
import {RequireAuthentication } from "../screens"

```
const DrawerNav = () => {
  return (
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home"  
      >
        <Drawer.Screen name="My Orders" component={RequireAuthentication(OrderList)} />

      </Drawer.Navigator>
  )
}
```

Thank you